# Can I create a MediaWiki without Wiki Syntax (only HTML)?

Tags: html, mediawiki

My company likes to use a MediaWiki. But they are using special WYSIWYG editors (CKeditor) with special parsing algorithm to transfer HTML to WikiSystax.

Is there a way, to include other editors like TinyMCE and save the output only as HTML?

Comment: What's the point of using MediaWiki if you want to store content as HTML? There are wiki engines which specialize in that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a check at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TinyMCE_MW once. I hope this should help and meets your requirements.